# Why can we ignore the absolute value when solving certain homogeneous differential equations?

Tags: calculus, homogeneous-equation

I have a question about the solution to the following homogeneous differential equation: $ydx=(x+\sqrt{xy})dy$. Specifically, I am struggling to understand the textbook's solution to it, which is:
$$ydx=(x+\sqrt{xy})dy$$
$$y=vx, dy=xdv+vdx$$
$$vxdx=(x+x\sqrt{v})(vdx+xdv)$$
I understand the substitution part of the solution, but in the last line they are writing $\sqrt{vx^2}$ as $x\sqrt{v}$, without putting the absolute value bars around $x$. Why is the absolute value neglected? Shouldn't it be $|x|\sqrt{v}$? In general, my textbook seems to be quite loosey with dropping absolute values in differential equations, is it correct to do so? This is the rest of the solution:
$$vxdx=(x+x\sqrt{v})(vdx+xdv) \implies -xv\sqrt{v}dx=x^2(1+\sqrt{v})dv$$
$$\implies -\frac{dx}{x}=\left(v^{-\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{1}{v} \right)dv$$
$$\int -\frac{dx}{x}=\int \left(v^{-\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{1}{v} \right)dv$$
$$-\ln|x|+c=-2\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}+\ln\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|\implies 2\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}=\ln|y|-c$$
$$\implies 4x=y(\ln|y|-c)^2$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $xy$ is negative $\sqrt{xy}$ doesn't exist, so the book assumes that $x,y \ge0 $, I guess.

Comment: But what if $x,y<0$? In this case $\sqrt{xy}$ exists, yet the solution steps will change. I am really confused...

Comment: If you consider the case $x,y \le0$ you will end up with
$$
\ln|x|=-2\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}-\ln\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|+c
$$ and the solution will be the same. I agree that would have been better if specified

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. Thank you for clarifying! :)